# In QuickBase, is there a way to add a drilldown report to a formula field?

Tags: quickbase

One thing I appreciate about QuickBase table to table relationship summary formulas is that they automatically are hyperlinked to a drilldown report (e.g., if I had a field that counted the # of passing scores for a person and the person had 2, then there's automatically a link to the parent table/report and if I click it, I can see both of that individual's passing score records).

Unfortunately, I lose that functionality when writing a formula outside of the table-to-table default options (e.g., the # of passing scores divided by the # of passing + non-passing scores does not give option to add a drilldown report). Is there a way to add drilldown to a formula field? The closest I got was adding a report link field, but it'd be nice if that was a hyperlink with a number to avoid taking unnecessary space.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do that using a Formula Rich Text field with an HTML hyperlink and adding a query parameter in your URL. You can get some help building the query if you turn off the new report style, then going to More > Show the expanded URL for this report. The expanded URL should look like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the Rich text field.
I prefer to build a query instead of using the expanded one.
The expanded url has a temporary id :(

Here is an example how you can create an own link if you use  a formula Rich text field.

For sure, you have to replace a couple of variables in the following link ;)

```
// qid=1      >> id of your drilldown report
// mx{6.TV.2} >> 6 is the related field's id, 2 is the key of your table (master)
// the numbers are just an examples
// _DBID_TEMPLATES_CHILDREN >> you can find it at bottom of the children table's 
   advanced settings

"<a href=\""& URLRoot() & "db/" & [_DBID_TEMPLATES_CHILDREN] & "? 
 a=s&qid=1&dlta=mx{6.TV.2}&opts=disprec&isDDR=1\"> "& [# of Templates childs] &" </a>"
```